# Reading multiple Values in JSON-Array through pandas

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

I have defined this method to read from JSON-Files, but it doesnt work with multiple results. Can I modify this code read out every result in the given Array?

The Input: `(phase = Split of name, e.g "Test01" from "01_Test01_Version1.json", testReport = deepcopy of Json-file )`

```py
COLUMNS = ['Intermediate test', 'Sub-test', 'Measurement', 'Date','Time', 'Unit', 'Value', 'Comment']
EP_PRESSURE = ['ambient','1.50 bar','150.00 bar']

def formatTestsResults(phase, testReport):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(100), columns=COLUMNS)
    
    line = -1
    for test in [1,2,3]:
        for i, pressure in enumerate(EP_PRESSURE):
            try:
                measurements = testReport['EP test V%s %s'%(test,pressure)]['MEASUREMENTS']
            except KeyError:
                continue
            
            for param, measurement in sorted(measurements.items()):
                
                if type(measurement) == list:
                    print('There are multiple test data, the last one is taken into account')
                    measurement = measurement[-1]
                    
                line += 1
                df['Intermediate test'][line] = phase
                df['Sub-test'][line] = 'Electrical tests'
                df['Measurement'][line] = 'V%i %s at %s'%(test,param,pressure)
                df['Unit'][line] = measurement['RESULTS'][param]['UNIT']
                df['Date'][line] = convertDate(measurement['RESULTS'][param]['TIMESTAMP'][0:10])
                df['Time'][line] = convertTime(measurement['RESULTS'][param]['TIMESTAMP'][11:])
                df['Value'][line] = measurement['RESULTS'][param]['VALUE']
                df['Comment'][line] = ''
    
    return df
```

The JSON looks something like this, but a few thousand lines long:

```
    "TESTS": {
        "EP test V1 ambient": {
            "MEASUREMENTS": {
                "Coil resistance": [
                    {
                        "RESULTS": {
                            "Coil resistance": {
                                "DESCRIPTION": null,
                                "TIMESTAMP": "2000-10-10 10:10:00",
                                "UNIT": "Ohm",
                                "VALUE": 20.000000
                            },
                            "Coil resistance (50 degC)": {
                                "DESCRIPTION": null,
                                "TIMESTAMP": "2000-10-10 10:10:20",
                                "UNIT": "Ohm",
                                "VALUE": 10.00000000000
                            }
                        },
                        "START_TIME": "2000-10-10 10:10:00"
                    }
                ]
           }
       },
       "EP test V2 ambient": {
            "MEASUREMENTS": {
                "Coil resistance": [
                    {
                        "RESULTS": {
                            "Coil resistance": {
                                "DESCRIPTION": null,
                                "TIMESTAMP": "2000-10-10 10:10:00",
                                "UNIT": "Ohm",
                                "VALUE": 20.000000
                            },
                            "Coil resistance (50 degC)": {
                                "DESCRIPTION": null,
                                "TIMESTAMP": "2000-10-10 10:10:20",
                                "UNIT": "Ohm",
                                "VALUE": 10.00000000000
                            }
                        },
                        "START_TIME": "2000-10-10 10:10:00"
                    }
                ]
           }
       },
       "EP test V1 1.50 bar": {
            "MEASUREMENTS": {
                "Coil resistance": [
                    {
                        "RESULTS": {
                            "Coil resistance": {
                                "DESCRIPTION": null,
                                "TIMESTAMP": "2000-10-10 10:10:00",
                                "UNIT": "Ohm",
                                "VALUE": 20.000000
                            },
                            "Coil resistance (50 degC)": {
                                "DESCRIPTION": null,
                                "TIMESTAMP": "2000-10-10 10:10:20",
                                "UNIT": "Ohm",
                                "VALUE": 10.00000000000
                            }
                        },
                        "START_TIME": "2000-10-10 10:10:00"
                    }
                ]
           }
       }
   }
```

Desired Output as Excel sheet:

```
Test | Sub-test        | Measurement                             | Date       | Time     | Unit | Value          | Comment
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test | Electrical Test | V1 Coil resistance at ambient            | 10.10.2000 | 10:10:00 | Ohm  | 20.000000      |
Test | Electrical Test | V1 Coil resistance (50 degC) at ambient  | 10.10.2000 | 10:10:20 | Ohm  | 10.00000000000 |
Test | Electrical Test | V2 Coil resistance at ambient            | 10.10.2000 | 10:10:20 | Ohm  | 20.000000      |
Test | Electrical Test | V2 Coil resistance (50 degC) at ambient  | 10.10.2000 | 10:10:20 | Ohm  | 10.00000000000 |
Test | Electrical Test | V1 Coil resistance at 1.50 bar           | 10.10.2000 | 10:10:20 | Ohm  | 20.000000      |
Test | Electrical Test | V1 Coil resistance (50 degC) at 1.50 bar | 10.10.2000 | 10:10:20 | Ohm  | 10.00000000000 |
```

Because I dont know how to include both results of the Array, the code only gets me one, but I would like the option to read out and save every one of them.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please add the example of input and output you would like to achieve?

Comment: I showed what the output would be like! Input are just json files in a directory with information like in the example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you would like to achieve so can not write down the code for you.
But so far, I can see there's a problem in the code you wrote:

`measurement['RESULTS'][param]['UNIT']`

The `param` is the name of the measurement. You need another iteration in the results array.

I assumed that you would like to retrieve the last measurement item only then we could do:

```py
for param, measurement in sorted(measurements.items()):
 # ...
    for _, mesurementResult in measurement['RESULTS']:
        df['Unit'].append(mesurementResult['UNIT'])
```

You might need to update the `line` into an appropriate values. Because the results might have more than 1 line.

The function might like:

```
def formatTestsResults(phase, testReport):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(100), columns=COLUMNS)

    line = 0
    for test in [1,2,3]:
        for i, pressure in enumerate(EP_PRESSURE):
            try:
                measurements = testReport['EP test V%s %s'%(test,pressure)]['MEASUREMENTS']
            except KeyError:
                continue

            for param, measurement in sorted(measurements.items()):
                if type(measurement) == list:
                    print('There are multiple test data, the last one is taken into account')
                    measurement = measurement[-1]


                if 'RESULTS' in measurement and measurement['RESULTS']:
                    for key, res in measurement['RESULTS'].items():
                        df['Intermediate test'][line] = phase
                        df['Sub-test'][line] = 'Electrical tests'
                        df['Measurement'][line] = 'V%i %s at %s'%(test,param,pressure)
                        df['Unit'][line] = res['UNIT']
                        df['Date'][line] = convertDate(res['TIMESTAMP'][0:10])
                        df['Time'][line] = convertTime(res['TIMESTAMP'][11:])
                        df['Value'][line] = res['VALUE']
                        df['Comment'][line] = ''

                        line += 1

    return df
```

Comment: Although this really does work and extracts all the information, it gets rid of this line: ```measurements = testReport['EP test V%s %s'%(test,pressure)]['MEASUREMENTS']```, which is needed to iterate all the information e.g there isnt only one 'EP test V1 ambient', it also could be 'EP test V2 ambient' or ''EP test V3 ambient 'EP test V1 150bar' etc.
This is a mistake on my part because I forgot to include the line in the question, im sorry for that. Is it possible to do this code while preserving this loop?
But thanks, this has been a huge help already!

Comment: @StevenRutger I don't have enough context of what you're doing, so can not give you the exact function.

But I think you can replace: `measurements = testReport['TESTS']['EP test V1 ambient']['MEASUREMENTS` by your command `measurements = testReport['EP test V%s %s'%(test,pressure)]['MEASUREMENTS']`.

Comment: The problem is, that the statement will throw an exception, because the parameters (test,pressure) come from the for loops, which you got rid off c:
I updated the question and added more examples and output, so hopefully it will be clearer!

Comment: Okay, I see, then please uncomment the for loop contained test, pressure. I commented for testing purpose.

Comment: @StevenRutger I updated the code, if it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you.